# C# как вызвать имненной конструктор в мейне

Tags: c#, конструктор

Например, есть 3 конструктора

```
private Const()
{
 \\тут пусто 
}

public Const Name1(string param)
{
\\ реализация
}

public Const Name2(string param)
{
\\ реализация
}
```

И я хочу вызвать их в мейне

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Name1 = new Name1(param);
   Name2 = new Name2(param);
}
```

Наподобие этого, если конечно это возможно.

Comment: Нет, это невозможно.

Comment: `Name1` и `Name2` не выглядят как конструкторы. Если вы имеете в виду идиому named constructor, то она оформлена у вас неправильно: методы должны быть статическими.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Const
{
  private Const()
  {
    \\тут пусто 
  }

  public static Const Name1(string param)
  {
    \\ реализация
  }

  public static Const Name2(string param)
  {
    \\ реализация
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Const Name1 = Const.Name1("param1");
   Const Name2 = Const.Name2("param2");
}
```